# aplay not working when spawn inside nodejs, but works fine from command-line

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I have this simple command that runs just fine from the command line:

`aplay --format=S16_LE --rate=24000 -D sysdefault ./test.wav`

However, when I run it inside nodejs from the spawn, it does not work,

`var aplay = cp.spawn('aplay', [
    '--format=S16_LE',
    '--rate=24000',
    '-D sysdefault',
    './test.wave']);`

I get the following message from stderr

`ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) 
Unknown PCM  sysdefault
aplay: main:722: 
audio open error: No such file or directory`

I am using a raspberry pi with a usb audio device.

Also, it does not work when i change -D sysdefault to -D plughw:0,0

Thanks for any help you can provide me.